# Getting <aside> to line up horizontally with mainSection

Tags: html, css

What would be the best way of lining up all of my aside elements with the mainSection element (i.e. on the right hand side) in the fluid width layout I am currently developing. I've tried everything but nothing is working.

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7zvfe8n/1/

**HTML code**

```
<section class="mainSection">
    <div class="section">
        <!-- POST 1 -->
        <article class="content">
             <h2><a href="a" title="First post">T Events</a></h2>

            <p class="post-info">This post is written by Johnny</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a felis ornare, convallis risus sed, imperdiet tortor. Fusce congue at neque vel viverra. Vivamus condimentum cursus pulvinar. Sed nec malesuada mauris, vel tincidunt augue. Nullam orci quam, interdum sit amet dictum eget, posuere eget dui. Integer placerat lectus sed tincidunt condimentum. Vestibulum tincidunt ex ac odio tempus, nec rutrum ante commodo.</p>
            <br/>
            <p>Nam et diam nec velit pellentesque hendrerit et non arcu. Duis non nisl tincidunt arcu laoreet sollicitudin quis et dui. Etiam eget velit tempor, maximus orci vel, maximus augue. Nunc imperdiet quis enim vitae auctor. Nullam vitae tortor porta, faucibus tellus et, maximus erat. Morbi varius consectetur luctus. Donec laoreet pellentesque mi vitae tristique. In laoreet lectus vitae tortor fermentum sollicitudin. Vestibulum sit amet nunc elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis rhoncus facilisis. Quisque ac vestibulum lorem. Morbi nec justo dignissim, dignissim dui vel, vehicula turpis.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <article>
             <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>

            <p>Enter code: dolorem</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <article>
             <h2>CHRISTMAS BOOKINGS</h2>

            <p>Pellentesque a felis ornare, convallis risus sed.</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <article>
             <h2>Quote of the day:</h2>

            <p>Nam et diam nec velit pellentesque hendrerit et non arcu.</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainSection {
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.section {
    width: 70%;
}
.content {
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.sidebar:first-child {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.sidebar h2 {
    color:#F3C;
}
.sidebar:last-child {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting width for a child element and your `.mainSection` still takes 100% of the width, because that's how elements with `display: block` behave by default. This leaves no place for your `aside` elements to the right of it.

I just moved width property from .section to .mainSection: http://jsfiddle.net/z7zvfe8n/4/

```
 .mainSection {
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left; 
    width: 70%;
}
```